# When should application state update the database?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Im currently working on an application which uses react, redux, graphql, apollo and MongoDB.
When the application first loads, im looking to populate the application local data using the database, from there use the application state for any further display to the view. My problem is, im not sure when to make a call to the database given this particular stack

Comment: You want to know when, after loading data from your database, you should make an update to the database? A good rule of thumb is - whenever you have information that you need to persist across sessions.

Comment: Thank you, im very inexperienced with application development. So essentially session ends update DB?

Comment: You're asking a very broad question.  Whenever the user does anything that you want persisted, you need to save that to the DB.  I can't give you any specifics with the minimal detail included in your question but for example: if my app was a todo list, I would want to save anytime a user creates, updates, or deletes a todo list item.

Answer (score 0):

All service call should be done in componentDidMount() life cycle method or you can Use middleware like thunk to call sync service call or db call.

componentDidMount(): After mounting component call service and set state, this state will be used on UI to render any data.

Middleware: You dispatch an action like load products. This will call middle ware to call service and store details in redux store. This can render data on UI.

Let me know if you need more explanation. This is most common architecture which people use for react apps.